# Laravel relationship does not seem to work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I've got a fresh project and wanted to lay down some relationships. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

I've got a COMPANY model with

```
public function owner() 
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'owner_id');
}
```

And then a USER model with

```
public function owns()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company', 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

When I get the user or company object, the relation does not show. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your db structure or migrations

Comment: public function owner() 
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'owner_id');
}

Comment: You are missing a return on your owner relation.

Comment: @AlexHarris this was actually the problem... derp... thanks! If you make an answer out of it I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid problems with many parameters.

```
...
public function owner() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'owner_id');
}
...
```

and

```
...
public function owns()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Company', 'owner_id');
}
...
```

What is the output when you try to access `$some_user->owns`?
You can test your relationships with `php artisan tinker`, then you can look for one of your users owns like this:

`$u = User::find(1)`
`$u->owns`

If it returns an array, your relation is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For your relationship mapping for the belongsTo you don't actually need to map the fields you have to map to start
only that

```
$this->belongsTo('App\User');
```

would have been enough

and for your just hasMany just

```
$this->hasMany('App\Company');
```

if the relationship field is user_id